# rhythmbox crashes due "Failed to import the site module"

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox, python3

I updated my machine from 15.10 to 16.04 a few days ago.

Now I have to face this strange Issue: `rhythmbox` tells me, that it *Failed to import the site module* and crashes, because `python3.5` is missing the module `_sysconfigdata_m`.

I had an installation from source of `python3.5.1`, but it seems like the release-uprgade removed this installation.
The old `python3.5.1`´s files were located under `/usr/lib/python3.5.1/`.

I already tried to reinstall `python3.5` and `rhythmbox`.

The complete traceback:

```
me@my_machine:~$ rhythmbox
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
   main()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main
   known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
   user_site = getusersitepackages()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
   user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
   USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
   return get_config_vars().get(name)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
   _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
   from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
   from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

***btw***:
It seems like 16.04 removed `python3.4` (my default `python3`) and replaced it with `python3.2`.

Linking `/usr/bin/python3.2` to `/usr/bin/python3` just caused other `python3` programs, like gnome-termial to crash.

***Other*** forums said, that this error appears, if `python2` is used instead of `python3` so I am a kind of stuck.

***Update***:
I added some debug output in `/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py`:

```
print(sys.version)
```

The output is

```
3.5.1 (default, Feb 10 2016, 15:13:13) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]
```

but it should be

```
3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330]
```

I have **no such `python3` installation on my machine!** I have searched **several times** for such an installation.

***Edit***:

I tried to completely reinstall `python3` by running

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge python3
```

***DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME!***

This will remove **nearly all programs** on your machine. It took me 6h just to rebuild my base system! I had only *one* `gnome-terminal` left, because it was loaded into ram.

But this did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

***This is not a solution but a fix***
I added

```
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

to `/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py`. The path `/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu` was substituted with `/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-gnu`.

***Fixing it***

I fixed it by adding the following workaround to the file:

```
plat_path = "/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu"
if(not plat_path in sys.path):
    sys.path.append(plat_path)
```

I still do not know why this happened.