# missing package CommandNotFound

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python3

I recently updated from 15.10 to 16.04 and now my `python3` seems to be messed up.

Before the upgrade I had `python3.4` and `python3.5.1`(manually) installed. The upgrade removed `python3.4` and replaced it with `python3.2` and `python3.1`.
The new `python3.5.1` removed my `python3.5.1` installtion.

But now I am facing a lot of issues:

- [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765566/rhythmbox-crashes-due-failed-to-import-the-site-module)
- `comand-not-found` does not work anymore and crashes with this traceback (1)
- if I try to run `commmand-not-found` with `python3.2` (2)

I stripped a few more stuff, as it is always the same.

I do not want to use the old `python3` versions, so how can I fix this?
And **why** is there `python3.1`?

(1)

```
 me@my-machine:~$ whareis systemd     
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
     from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
 ImportError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
```

(2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named _gdbm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: Unlike I mentioned before my `python3.5.1` installation was not removed by the update. It was still under `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`.

**Tracing the Error**: I wrote a few debug lines into `/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py`:

```
print("python-version", sys.version_info)
print("python-gcc-version",sys.version)
print("python-executable",sys.executable)
```

The output was different between calling `/usr/bin/python3` and `rhythmbox`, but the python-executable was in both ways `/usr/bin/python3`

Then I searched for the wrong installation  using `whereis python3`
and removed  `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`

Then I purged and reinstalled `python3` and ran `apt install -f`.
So this Error disappeared.

**Remember**: never install stuff from source, if it might be in the repos sometime or, at least remove it before your package manager installs it.

Answer (score 1):

Saw the same error in Ubuntu `16.04` with **two** installations of Python3 (`3.5.2` and `3.7.3`):

```
$ junk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
```

I didn't need python `3.5.2`. So, removing it by doing the following resolved the error for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then, I see `command not found` as expected:

```
$ junk
junk: command not found
```