# python ModuleNotFoundError : 'CommandNotFound'

Tags: python, pip

when I opened terminal and `$ pip install -U pip setuptools`, I got an error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
```

I use python3.5, and its path is `/usr/bin/python3.5`

I tried to find CommandNotFound package but I can't find it.

How can I fix this error?

---

[edit] : OS Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766246/missing-package-commandnotfound)

**Solution:** Unlike I mentioned before my `python3.5.1` installation was not removed by the update. It was still under `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`.

**Tracing the Error:** I wrote a few debug lines into `/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py`:

```
print("python-version", sys.version_info)
print("python-gcc-version",sys.version)
print("python-executable",sys.executable)
```

The output was different between calling `/usr/bin/python3` and `rhythmbox`, but the `python-executable` was in both ways `/usr/bin/python3`

When I searched for the wrong installation using where is python3 and 
removed

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5
```

Then I purged and reinstalled python3 and ran `apt install -f`.
So this Error disappeared.

Remember: never install stuff from source, if it might be in the repos sometime or, at least remove it before your package manager installs it.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more answer, as I also encountered this issue and happened to solve it.
This issue happened when I installed python3.7 from source.

Check /usr/lib/command-not-found file, it is trying to find module `CommandNotFound`, which is NOT shipped with python3.7 but DOES with Ubuntu under directory `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

What we need to do is adding the directory to python import path:

1. `vi .bashrc` (or .profile)
2. add line
   `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`
   Pay attention that you may need to change the `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` to your own directory.
3. exit and `source .bashrc` (or .profile)

Comment: This is on the right track for me, but pointing `python3` to one's own source install opens a can of worms (`lsb_release` e.g. does not work anymore and can't be installed because the install process calls it as well??). So at least for 16.04 it's better not to mess with the Python 3 version from the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed a new python3 version from source, and re-link symbol-link in `/usr/bin/pyton3` from `python3.5`(or other system python version, it's python3.5 in ubuntu16.04) to `/usr/local/bin/python3`(or other location you installed the new python version). I solved the problem by following steps:

1. check the python3 symbol link using `ls -la /usr/bin/python3*`.
2. if it links `/usr/local/bin/python3` or other location where you installed the new python version, delete it using `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/python3`.
3. re-link the python3 to system python3 version using `sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3', python3.5 is the system python version, you can comfirm it in step 1.

Then the error disappeared when you execute an unknow command.